# generating random numbers from a set such that each number gets picked using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array arr[8,4,2,1,7,5,3,0] which has 8 elements. I want to pick each number from the array randomly such that each number gets picked and none gets repeated. I want each number to be picked only once.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is....

```js
let numbers = [8,4,2,1,7,5,3,0];
let shuffle = (o) => {
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

console.log(shuffle(numbers))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd simplify this and just have a basic `while` loop:

```
const array=[8,4,2,1,7,5,3,0];

while(array.length>0) {
  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(array.length));
  console.log(`Picked this number: ${array[i]}`);
  array.splice(i,1);
};
```

Sample output:

```
// "Picked this number: 5"
// "Picked this number: 1"
// "Picked this number: 0"
// "Picked this number: 7"
// "Picked this number: 8"
// "Picked this number: 2"
// "Picked this number: 3"
// "Picked this number: 4"
```

Codepen: http://jsbin.com/bukoqujupo/edit?js,console

So all this does is count the number of elements in your array, pick one randomly, spit it out and then remove it from the array. It carries on (`while`) the array contains elements. Once it's picked all of them out it stops running.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this ?

```js
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

let arr = [8, 4, 2, 1, 7, 5, 3, 0],
  selectedIndex = [];

function getRandomValue() {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(arr.length));
  if (selectedIndex.indexOf(randomIndex) !== -1) {
    return getRandomValue()
  }
  selectedIndex.push(randomIndex);
  return arr[randomIndex]
}
arr.forEach(() => {
  console.log(getRandomValue());

})
```